# Decorating data from related model in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `Property` model and a `Pricing Summary` model, which relate to each other and are shown below:

```
App.Property = DS.Model.extend({
    totalRoomCount: DS.attr(),
    name: DS.attr(),
    address: DS.attr(),
    city: DS.attr(),
    state: DS.attr(),
    zip: DS.attr(),
    pricingSummaries: DS.hasMany('pricingSummary', {async: true})
});

App.PricingSummary = DS.Model.extend({
    startDate: DS.attr(),
    endDate: DS.attr(),
    days: DS.hasMany('day', {async: true}),
    property: DS.belongsTo('property', {async: true})
});
```

Inside of my Property route I set the model to a `Property`, and then in the template, I want to output a list of the `PricingSummary`'s that are related to that `Property`, as follows:

```
{{#each pricingSummary in pricingSummaries}}

{{render 'summaryRow' pricingSummary}}

{{/each}}
```

This works, and I'm able to output the attributes of each particular `PricingSummary` inside of the `summaryRow` template, like its `startDate` and `endDate`, for example. But what I REALLY want to do here is modify/format the `startDate` and output this formatted version. Basically I think I want a controller at this point, but I don't know how to tie a controller to the specific Pricing Summary model being output.

How do I do this? And furthermore, you can see that a `PricingSummary` also has a relationship to my `Day` model, so I'm going to want to do this again, another level deep.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, and all of them are relatively simple.

In relation to actually decorating a model, the easiest method would be to create a computed property on the model itself.  Some people don't like this because they believe the models should be skinny and decorators should be in controllers/components, but it's all up to your preference.  You could accomplish it this way:

```
App.YourModel = DS.Model.extend({
  date: attr('date'),
  formattedDate: function() {
    var date = this.get('date');
    return date ? this.get('date').toDateString() : null ; // Use your own format :-)
  }.property('date')
});
```

Alternatively, I like to use a getter/setter pattern so you can use two-way bindings and it will marshal the value to a date on set, or to a string on get.  In the following example, I'm using `moment.js` to parse/format:

```
App.YourModel = DS.Model.extend({
  date: attr('date'),
  dateMarshal: function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      var parsed = moment(value);
      this.set('date', parsed.isValid() ? parsed.toDate() : null);
    }
    return this.get('date') ? moment(this.get('date')).format('MM/DD/YYYY') : null ;
  }.property('date'),
});
```

Another option would be to provide an `itemController` property to the `{{#each}}` helper, but that's effectively the same as using render without having to use a custom view.

If you're using more properties and perhaps some actions on the pricing summary row (to delete it, for instance), my preference would be to use a component:

```
{{#each pricingSummary in pricingSummaries}}
  {{pricing-summary-item content=pricingSummary}}
{{/each}}
```

And your component:

```
App.PricingSummaryItem = Ember.Component.extend({
  content: null,
  dateFormatted: function() {
    var formattedDate = this.get('content.date');
    // Format your date
    return formattedDate;
  }.property('content.date')
  actions: {
    'delete': function() {
      this.get('content').deleteRecord();
    },
    markRead: function() {
      this.set('content.isRead', true);
      this.get('content').save();
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, to address JUST the date issue and not decoration, I would make a bound helper.  Again, this example uses `moment.js` (and I'm using `ember-cli` as well, so pardon the ES6 syntax):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function formatDate(input, options) {
  input = moment(input);
  if (options.hashContexts.fromNow) {
    return input.fromNow();
  } else {
    return input.format(options.hash.format || 'LL');
  }
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(formatDate);
```

Then you just use `{{format-date yourDateProperty}}` in your template.

Comment: Thanks for providing numerous options. I'd rather do this kind of thing in the controller I think, rather than the models themselves, and I was able to get a controller synced with the template I'm rendering. But I'm having issues there... Posted a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569439/accessing-a-model-from-a-controller-in-ember

Comment: The syntax is exactly the same regardless of whether you put the computed property in the model, a controller, or a component.  The property path might be different, but the implementation is the same.  Your controller should basically look like the component above.

Comment: And I answered your other question as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answers on both questions! You've been incredibly helpful!