# Accessing a model from a controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a pretty basic setup where I'm trying to format a date in my Controller. The problem is I can't access it in the `formattedStart` function below, whereas I CAN access it in the `summaryRowAction` handler. This is baffling me, because console.logging `this` in both places gives the same result. But for some reason inside of `formattedStart`, `this.get('model.startDate')` is undefined.

```
App.SummaryRowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    formattedStart: function(){
        console.log(this.get('model.startDate');)
        return this.get('model.startDate');
    }.property(),

    actions: {
        summaryRowAction: function(){
            console.log(this.get('model.startDate'));
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my model and my template (in Jade) for reference:

```
App.PricingSummary = DS.Model.extend({
    startDate: DS.attr(),
    endDate: DS.attr(),
    days: DS.hasMany('day', {async: true}),
    property: DS.belongsTo('property', {async: true})
});

script(type="text/x-handlebars", data-template-name="summaryRow")
    .summaries__summary("{{action 'summaryRowAction'}}")
        .summaries__summary--item{{formattedStart}} &mdash; {{endDate}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the first (and only) time that the property is evaluated, `model` is actually `null`.  You need to specify `startDate` as a dependency in the property so Ember knows to re-evaluate when the data changes.  Also, you don't need `model.*` in an object controller, the properties are automatically delegated to `content`/`model`

So:

```
formattedStart: function(){
    console.log(this.get('startDate');)
    return this.get('startDate');
}.property('startDate'),
```